# Identify the isomorphism of the group $D_6 / \langle\rho ^3\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

Identify the isomorphism of the group $D_6 / \langle \rho ^3\rangle$  among the following options. Choose one.

$\mathbb{Z}_3, D_3, \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_6$

My thought is that since the index of $\langle \rho ^3\rangle $ is $2$, the number of cosets is $6$.

So I thought I only need to find a group of order $6$ but there are three of which the order is $6.$

Is there any other restrictions I need to consider?

Comment: Use `$\langle x\rangle$` for $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: ah..sorry I don't understand it. Could you elaborate out, please?

Comment: What you mean by $D_6$? Is it the dihedral of order 6 or 12?

Comment: @AntonioFicarra of order 12!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A presentation for $D_6$ is

$$\langle \rho ,\sigma \mid \rho^6, \sigma^2, \sigma \rho=\rho^{-1}\sigma\rangle,\tag{1}$$

so that taking the quotient of $D_6$ by $\langle \rho^3\rangle$ amounts to killing $\rho^3$; that is, setting it equal to the identity in $(1)$, like so:

$$\langle \rho ,\sigma \mid \rho^3, \sigma^2, \sigma \rho=\rho^{-1}\sigma\rangle.\tag{2}$$

The relation $\sigma \rho=\rho^{-1}\sigma$ stays the same, since $\rho^2=\rho^5=\rho^{-1}$.

But $(2)$ is just a presentation of $D_3$. Hence the answer is $D_3$.

Comment: Thank you so much, but could you briefly explain how you get a presentation for $D_6$ like that?

Comment: You're welcome, @jun. [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_Group/Group_Presentation) is a proof that the presentations given are of dihedral groups.

Comment: Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The order of $\Bbb Z_3$ is wrong.  Next $\Bbb Z_3×\Bbb Z_2\cong\Bbb Z_6$.  But $\Bbb Z_6$ is out, because of the fact that $\langle\rho^3\rangle=Z(D_6)$.  It's well known that if a group modulo its center is cyclic, then the group is abelian.

We are left with $D_3$.  As a check, it is well-known that $D_6\cong S_3\times\Bbb Z_2$.  Finally, $S_3\cong D_3$.